# htaccess extract first part of url, whilst allowing folder/file access

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to extract company name from a URL;

`www.example.com/company-name/`

The URL will always be prefixed with the company name.

How can I extract this but allow access to files/folders that exist?

Here's what I currently have, its returning a 404;

`RewriteRule ^([a-z,A-Z,0-9,-]+)/?$ /?CompanyName=$1 [NC,L,QSA]`

N.B. Would prefer not to implement a controller

Comment: thanks Croises, the answer is rewriting from ^blog/ I would like to rewrite from base.

Comment: You're getting a RTFM response because there's nothing even slightly unique about your use case. You could find hundreds of articles and answers that would solve it.